# data generator with tensorflow on the gpu

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am making a neural network using tensorflow and I ran into a problem trying to use a generator to split my data up, basically it's too slow.

My training data consists of 52x52 numpy arrays. I need to split each array into a 52x52x3 array before I input it into my NN. As mentioned I have a generator working that does this, but I noticed that even though my NN is running on the GPU my GPU usage is very low (under 10% usually). I think this might be caused by me doing the generator on the CPU.

Is there any way of running my generator on the GPU?

What I tried:
- I thought of trying to use pyCUDA in order to program the generator on the GPU but found that tensorflow and pyCUDA don't support each other
-I tried using the `from_generator` function from the Dataset API as mentioned here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset
But while having issues with it I ran into this github thread mentioning that this function isn't supported to run on the GPU anyway:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by splitting a 52x52 array into a 52x52x3 array? That doesn’t parse to me. A bit more context about the input data would be helpful.

Comment: Of course, from the original 52x52 numpy array I extract the entries of the array into three layers. If a number in the original array is not extracted to the one layer a 0 will take its place for that index in that specific layer. The 52x52 array is a codified image. In a similar way that many images are split into layers for RGB, except what I am doing with the original array is instead of RGB I make the different layers hold certain numbers from the original array.

Comment: You cannot vectorize this split in TensorFlow? If you have to use a python function outside of TensorFlow, I think using `tf.data` can still improve your efficiency. You can load the numpy arrays and use the `tf.data.Dataset.map` function with `num_parallel_calls` threads for the transformation.